# python - requests.get - raising exceptions to prevent doing the wrong thing

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-requests

I'm new to both requests and exceptions, so please forgive me for my ignorance. Reading the docs has only got me so far, so thanks for any help!

My thinking is that if I have some function that calls a request, and some function that uses the output of that and so on, I only need to put the

```
try:
    do something
except:
    do something else
```

part in the topmost function? If I use that format in all my functions, will it still raise exceptions up the chain, or does the try/except format "use-up" the exception? Say an exception is raised when I make the request, and in that function I have a try/except layout, does the try/except layout get called on the other functions as well?

I basically never want my code to continue if it doesn't receive data. So I've written a basic get function. Is this approach reasonable?

```
def requestGet(url,params=None):
    r = requests.get(url,params=params)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception('Request did not perform as expected, status code %s'%r.status_code)
    return r
```

Comment: Might want to consider [raise_for_status](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes)

Answer (score 0):

If an error occurs in the try portion of your code the except portion will be executed and the exception will not be raised unless you specifically raise it.  If an exception occurs in the except portion then that exception will be raised further.

If you want it to pass the exception up the chain you can do this:

```
try:
     something
except Exception as e:
     something else
     raise e
```